# Which of these packages am I looking for to install Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, amazon-web-services

I am a programmer who has to configure a server to run Linux, Apache, and Python (with Django). When I type `apache2` into my terminal, it responds with the following: 
**The program 'apache2' can be found in the following packages:

* apache2-mpm-event

* apache2-mpm-prefork

* apache2-mpm-worker

* apache2-mpm-itk

Try: sudo apt-get install `<selected package>`**

Which one of these am I looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This will install apache2 using the most common way for your system and starts the server after the installation has finished. The default document root will be `/var/www`.

If you need additional python support (as apache module) type:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now you should be able to serve `*.py` files from `/var/www` and it's sub directories

Comment: Probably you dwant libpache2-mod-wsgi instead of mod_python; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 1):

For django you can also use libapache2-mod-wsgi as apache module